# Docker-Compose + Volume + NodeJs - changes not reflected when saved

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose

directory structure

```
projectroot/
    docker-compose.yml
    frontend/
        Dockerfile
        src/
            node_modules
            package.json
            ....
```

projectroot/frontend/docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  frontend:
    build: ./frontend
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes:
      - ./frontend/src:/app/
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:12.18.3

COPY /src/package.json .

RUN npm install --save-dev

COPY /src .

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "run", "dev"]
```

The above works. I can run `docker-compose up` and my app is rendered on `localhost:3000`.

However when I make a change on projectroot/frontend/pages/index.js, that change isn't reflected.

I am confused because I copy the contents of /src over to /app in my Dockerfile (`COPY /src .`). If I run the container and bash in, I see `/app` folder with the contents of my host `/src` folder.

If I remove the `COPY` command from `Dockerfile`, the readout just loops the following:

```
$ docker-compose up
Recreating pricey_frontend_1 ... done
Attaching to pricey_frontend_1
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | > src@1.0.0 dev /
frontend_1  | > cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | [nodemon] 2.0.4
frontend_1  | [nodemon] to restart at any time, enter `rs`
frontend_1  | [nodemon] watching path(s): *.*
frontend_1  | [nodemon] watching extensions: js,mjs,json
frontend_1  | [nodemon] starting `npm run dev server.js`
frontend_1  |
frontend_1  | > src@1.0.0 dev /
frontend_1  | > cross-env NODE_ENV=development nodemon server.js "server.js"
*** loops until I kill it***
```

In my head, removing COPY makes sense because I want to use the host volume src (so that I can update it and the changes reflected on localhost:3000 immediately. What am I missing?

Comment: You don't have a `WORKDIR` declaration in your Dockerfile, so the application is installed and runs out of `/`.  The bind mount into `/app` isn't getting used.  (But you might find a local Node installation much more convenient, especially for front-end code.)

Comment: Thanks. `WORKDIR` (I had used  in prev. attempt) stops it looping, and the app runs. But when I make a change locally, it's still not changed. If I restart the container the changes are there. The app uses Nextjs. If I run it `npm run dev` locally and make a change, the whole app recompiles/restarts. I think I'll just run the db container and connect the local app during dev. Thanks again

Comment: check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54126848/why-nextjs-using-docker-container-did-not-reload-after-changed-code-for-dev-envi

Answer (score 0):

check this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60633161/nodemon-not-restarting-server-on-code-change-in-docker-container?rq=1) i add `--legacy-watch` and now it's responding to changes.

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "nodemon", "--legacy-watch", "--inspect=0.0.0.0", "./src/server.js"]
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to pass `--legacy-watch` and `--inspect` flags to nodemon on package.json:

```json
"scripts": {
        "start": "node ./src/app.js",
        "dev": "nodemon --legacy-watch --inspect=0.0.0.0 ./src/app.js",
},
```

I had a separate `Dockerfile` for my Express app:

```yaml
FROM node:alpine

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package.json pnpm-lock.yaml ./

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install 

COPY src ./src

CMD ["pnpm", "dev"]
```

And used it from the `docker-compose.yml` file like below:

```yaml
version: "3.9"
services:
    mongodb:
        image: prismagraphql/mongo-single-replica:5.0.3
        ports:
            - 27017:27017
        environment:
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME=${DATABASE_USERNAME}
            - MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD=${DATABASE_PASSWORD}

    express-app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - 3007:3007
        volumes:
            - ./src/:/usr/app/src/
            - /usr/app/node_modules
        environment:
            - DATABASE_URL=mongodb://${DATABASE_USERNAME}:${DATABASE_PASSWORD}@mongodb:27017/test?authSource=admin&directConnection=true
        depends_on:
            - mongodb
```

Key points:

- You need to add a volume to sync your local files with the docker container
- You need to exclude your `node_modules` because there might be OS-specific requirements/installations for the packages you use. So, restarting the development environment whenever you add a package would be best.